# Measuring the joint probability of two data

Tags: regression, joint-distribution

I am looking at two data sets $(X_{1i}, X_{2i})$ and $(Y_{1i}, Y_{2i})$.  I understand that the conditional probability $P(X\mid Y)$ is given by:

$$P(X=x\mid Y=y) = \frac{P(X=x\ \cap Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}$$

but I do not know I can begin measuring this from the data set.  Is there a way I can apply regression to this problem?

The information is collected about the number of votes two politicians have half way through, $(X_{1i}, X_{2i})$, and at the end of, $(Y_{1i}, Y_{2i})$, a campaign (so they are discrete).

Comment: It all depends on what these data mean and how they have been collected.  Could you include that information in your question?

Comment: Your formula for $P(X=x|Y=y)$ is definitely wrong!

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I fixed your definition of conditional probability.

Comment: My mistake!  I've added more information about the data

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends on the size of your dataset because if for example $X$ takes on $N_x$ values and $Y$ takes on $N_y$ values then you will have $N_xN_y$ different conditional values, which might get quite large. If it's tractable:

$$P(X=x\mid Y=y) = \frac{P(X=x\ \cap Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}=\frac{\#(X=x\cap Y=y)}{\# (Y=y)}.$$

where $\#$ is the number of datapoints you have satisfying the parenthetical criteria. In other words, subset your data via queries like $X=x\cap Y=y$ to get counts.